# Pause Mixcloud with script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, api, mixcloud

I'm putting together a wordpress site that pulls in a friends show on mixcloud, creating posts for each show. In the loop of the shows, each show has a play button that opens a popout with a mixcloud iframe.

Play button looks like:

```
<?php if (!empty($showurl)) { ;?><a class="vp-b" data-show-id="<?php echo $video_id ;?>" href="#" style="outline: none;">play</a><?php } ;?>
```

Popout like:

```
<div id="player" style="display:none;" class="YouTubePopUp-Wrap VideoPopUpWrap"><div class="Video-PopUp-Content"><div class="vp-flex vp-vt-soundcloud"><span onclick="exitPlayer()" id="popup_closer" class="YouTubePopUp-Close"></span><iframe id="player_frame" width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?autoplay=1&feed=%2Fjohncasey1048554%2F[replace_me]%2F" frameborder="0" ></iframe></div></div></div>
```

I'm using this code to tell it which episode to play:

```
     jQuery('.vp-b').click(function(e)
{
  var value = jQuery(this).attr('data-show-id');
  var str = document.getElementById("player").innerHTML; 
  var replace = "[replace_me]";
  var res = str.replace(replace, value);
  document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = res;
  jQuery('#player').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm happy enough with that. My issue comes when I want to close the window and reset the source.

```
 function exitPlayer() {
    jQuery('#player').hide();
    jQuery("#player_frame").attr("src","https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?autoplay=1&feed=%2Fjohncasey1048554%2F[replace_me]%2F");
}
```

Mixcloud triggers a 'Changes you made may not be saved.' alert every time.

I've determined that it doesn't do it if the show is paused, so I'm trying to figure out how to pause the show when the exit button is clicked. But I'm totally stuck.

I've included:

```
<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/widgetApi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But can't figure out from [here](https://www.mixcloud.com/developers/widget/) how I'd go about pausing mixcloud on exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...

I didn't figure out how to pause the mixcloud player on exit, but what I did instead was completely remove the ifram on exit and replace it with a new one. Which prevents the  'Changes you made may not be saved.' alert from triggering.

```
function exitPlayer() {
    jQuery('#player').hide();
    jQuery('#player_frame').remove();
    jQuery('#prepender').prepend('<iframe id="player_frame" width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?autoplay=1&feed=%2Fjohncasey1048554%2F[replace_me]%2F" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');

}
```

and

```
 <div id="player" style="display:none;" class="YouTubePopUp-Wrap VideoPopUpWrap"><div class="Video-PopUp-Content"><div class="vp-flex vp-vt-soundcloud"><span onclick="exitPlayer()" id="popup_closer" class="YouTubePopUp-Close"></span><div id="prepender"><iframe id="player_frame" width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?autoplay=1&feed=%2Fjohncasey1048554%2F[replace_me]%2F" frameborder="0" ></iframe></div></div></div></div>
```